# where can I find library settings on my sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

Where is library settings on a sharepoint site?
I am looking to change/check a few advanced settings but can't seem to locate it anywhere

Comment: Assuming 2010+, if you navigate to the library, there should be a section on the ribbon for Library Settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SharePoint 2010 and 2013, when you navigate to the library, there is a section on the ribbon for Library Settings.  It is under `Library Tools` > `Settings` > `Library Settings`.